# Probabilistic Logic

Tags: probability, logic

I was wondering if there is any system of logic that has been worked out that explicitly uses probabilistic notions at its foundation.  It would include ideas like, as a first principle, all statements are not be determined as true or false, but instead should be quantified with a number between 0 and 1.  So it simply avoids the law of the excluded middle.  I presume it might take Bayesian inference as a first principle as a way to define implication, i.e. the measure of truth of the statement $Y \implies X$ is given by
$$ P(X|Y) = \frac{P(X, Y)}{P(Y)} $$
These ideas are used throughout probability but I am looking for a system where they have been axiomatized.

Comment: This remembers me of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzzy_logic

Comment: Thanks.  That may very well be an answer.

Comment: You can see also Theodore Hailperin, [Sentential Probability Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=Iu8pSmBMg_oC&printsec=frontcover) (1996).